# URL Routing on ASP.net, need to get a parameter from the url

Tags: asp.net, url, .net-3.5, routes

I am developing group feature on asp.net application.
I want to give users direct access to groups, so I want the url to be

```
www.<domain>.com/<groupname>
```

I implemented URL Routing for this case, but the problem that I want to pass the group name an to asp page as parameter, how can I do that?

the actual path is `"~/Public/ViewGroup?group=<groupname>` , how to get this group name and add it to the virtual path?

Thanks

Comment: I tried it, worked on local server but in production not.

Comment: It worked on production; after adding these to web.config
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
<add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
</modules>
 
<handlers>             
<add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
</handlers>
</system.webServer>

Comment: Add the last configuration plus the configuration on system.web
 <compilation>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </assemblies>
</compilation>

 <httpModules>
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule"
       type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, 
             System.Web.Routing, 
             Version=3.5.0.0, 
             Culture=neutral, 
             PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />       
    </httpModules>

Answer (score 6):

The quick answer is use:

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
   "groupname",
   "{group}",
   "~/public/viewgroup"
);
```

And then instead of (or as well as) using `querystring` to extract the value in `~/public/viewgroup` code, you would instead extract the groupname from `RouteData` as follows.

```
ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["groupname"];
```

The other option is use the IIS rewrite module.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="groupname">
            <match url="^([^/]*)$" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="public/viewgroup?group={R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

If you really *must* pass the value as a new `querystring` value, and want to use Routing, then things get tricky. You actually have to define a custom handler and rewrite the path in order to append the routing values to the `querystring`.

```
public class RouteWithQueryHandler : PageRouteHandler
{
    public RouteWithQueryHandler(string virtualPath, bool checkPhysicalUrlAccess)
        : base(virtualPath, checkPhysicalUrlAccess)
    {
    }

    public RouteWithQueryHandler(string virtualPath)
        :base(virtualPath)
    {
    }

    public override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        var request = requestContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var query  = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(request.Url.Query);
        foreach (var keyPair in requestContext.RouteData.Values)
        {
            query[HttpUtility.UrlEncode(keyPair.Key)] = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(
                                               Convert.ToString(keyPair.Value));
        }
        var qs = string.Join("&", query);
        requestContext.HttpContext.RewritePath(
                             requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Path, null, qs);
        return base.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
    }
}
```

This can be registered as follows:

```
routes.Add("groupname", new Route("{groupname}/products.aspx",     
           new RouteWithQueryHandler("~/products.aspx", true)));
```

It's quite a lot of work to avoid just pulling the value out to the Routing data.

Comment: I'm using .net 3.5, so I am using Map.add method
routes.Add(new Route
                ("{groupname}", new GroupRouteHandler("~/Public/ViewGroup?group={groupname}")
                ));

it gave me this error: ~/Public/ViewGroup?group={groupname}' is not a valid virtual path

Comment: Sorry my bad ? is disallowed, you can use a rewrite rule.

Comment: You can you this with routing as well, trying to find the right sytnax.

Comment: I found that I can extract it from the request url itself, but the main problem that it is not working on production, all methods work on local only!!!!

Comment: I didn't reachto a way to get paramters directly so I used, routes.Add(new Route ("{groupname}", new GroupRouteHandler("~/Public/ViewGroup") )); 

and in viewgroup page, I extracted the name from the url.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC path style arguments (parameters) can be accessed in C# controller like so. Path argument to be retrieved is "id" which returns a value of "123".

**MVC Routing**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
}

//Test URL: http://localhost/MyProject/Test/GetMyId/123
```

**MyController.cs**

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public string GetMyId()
    {
        //ANSWER -> ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["id"]
        return ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString();
    }
}
```