# Parse Query string for URL Re-Write asp.net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, url-routing

I need to solve a problem with url rewrite using routing feature in asp.net 4.0.
when user type url like

> www.mysite.com/product.aspx?id=101

then right page shows but suppose if i change the page location and name and when user type url like

> www.mysite.com/product.aspx?id=101

then page not found error will occur.

So please tell me how could I solve this situation using asp.net 4.0 routing feature.
is it possible ?

I handler routing like and my sample code

```
 void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute
              ("Source", "Source/{ID}/{Title}", "~/Source.aspx");
        RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute
              ("Source1", "MyData/Source/{ID}/{Title}", "~/MyData/Source.aspx");
    }
```

The code above is just sample and I this way do the url rewrite. It is very easy.
But if I need to solve my above url mapping problem with routing then how could I do so and what kind of code I need to write in `Application_Start` event.

I want when user type

> www.mysite.com/product.aspx?id=101

then it should redirect to

> www.mysite.com/prod/Myproduct.aspx?prodid=101

This url. So please guide me how could I do this kind of mapping with the help of asp.net 4.0 routing feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you can route to a path containing a querystring is to use a custom handler. By default routing passes variables in the RouteData.

So you have 3 options.

1) write a custom route handler to rewrite the path taking RouteData and adding it to the querystring. I wrote some code similar code for [this in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298476/url-routing-on-asp-net-need-to-get-a-parameter-from-the-url).

2) update MyProduct.aspx to check for product `id` in the QueryString if not found in `prodid` and use `MapPageRoute` (the new page has access the the original querystring).

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute(
                    "product", 
                    "product.aspx",
                    "~/prod/myproduct.aspx");
```

3) use IIS7 rewrite rules

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="product">
            <match url="product.aspx?id=([0-9]+)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="prod/myproduct.aspx?prodid={R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: thanks...u gave product.aspx/{*prodid}. why * what is the meaning of *. also tell what other sign we can use.

Comment: i am getting error for *. the error text is "A catch-all parameter can only appear as the last segment of the route URL.
Parameter name: routeUrl" please guide me to solve it.

Comment: sorry I got the option 2 wrong, I was thinking of a different scenario - I've updated. the `*` makes the last a parameter to match everything after the last segment.